# JSON array order

Tags: android, json

I am using PHP as a middleman to access a MySql database and it returns the result of the query as a json string using `json_encode`, then display it within the TableLayout of the app, this is why order is important so I can line up the data and the headers.

After some research I found out that json does not enforce order so any time I call `new JSONArray(result)` it scrambles the json returned by PHP. Is there any way to preserve the order of the returned string? Or maybe I'm using the incorrect data structure on either end.

**Relevant PHP result**:

```
[{"FIELD1":"vsa","FIELD2":"dfs","FIELD3":"dsfa","FIELD4":"adsf","FIELD5":"23","ZIPCODE":"asdf","USERNAME":"asd","PASSWORD":"as","DATE1":"dsfa"}]
```

**Relevant Android Result After JSONArray(result):**

```
[{"ZIPCODE":"asdf","DATE1":"dsfa","FIELD3":"dsfa","FIELD2":"dfs","FIELD5":"23","FIELD4":"adsf","USERNAME":"asd","FIELD1":"vsa","PASSWORD":"as"}]
```

Comment: Why do you need to keep the same order? The order of properties of a JSON object should have no effect on your app. JSONArray itself doesn't (even in your case) reorder items, it's the JSONObject inside that gets its properties reordered, probably by the HashMap/Hashtable it's implemented on top of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reordering inside a JSON object is due to the fact that JSON objects are key/value pairs (not an indexed array), which by default are unordered. However, the JSON array is an ordered sequence of values (JSON objects).

Don't rely on order!

Source: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

Comment: Yeah I had to pass a string with the json object and parse it to maintain order.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen `new JSONArray(String)` change the order of anything, and I've used it a lot. However, what you have seems to be an array of length 1. Using `myJsonArray.getJsonObject(0).getString("ZIPCODE")` should still return the correct data, and as long as you query in the correct order (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, etc), you should be fine.